# LinkedIn API returning extra/incorrect login prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, linkedin-api

I have a Rails application running the omniauth-linkedin gem and linkedin gem (essentialy an API wrapper). When a user logs in, they receive a primary login prompt that displays to them the correct scopes (FULL PROFILE and EMAIL ADDRESS), as below:

[image]

However, after they log in, they get another login prompt that should not come up, and that ignores the initial scope request. It tells them that LinkedIN is only requesting their PROFILE OVERVIEW, which is incorrect:

[image]

The problem must lie in my auth_controller, and I think it has do to with the url that is created in one of the authentication stages (definitely right after the user enters their LinkedIn authentication credentials). Here is my auth_controller:

```
require 'linkedin'

class AuthController < ApplicationController

  def auth
    client = LinkedIn::Client.new(ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET'])
    request_token = client.request_token(:oauth_callback => "http://#{request.host_with_port}/callback")
    session[:rtoken] = request_token.token
    session[:rsecret] = request_token.secret
    redirect_to client.request_token.authorize_url
  end

  def callback
    client = LinkedIn::Client.new(ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET'])
    if session[:atoken].nil?
      pin = params[:oauth_verifier]
      atoken, asecret = client.authorize_from_request(session[:rtoken], session[:rsecret], pin)
      session[:atoken] = atoken
      session[:asecret] = asecret
      @user = current_user
      @user.uid = client.profile(:fields => ["id"]).id
      flash.now[:success] = 'Signed in with LinkedIn.'
    else
      client.authorize_from_access(session[:atoken], session[:asecret])
      @user.uid = client.profile(:fields => ["id"]).id
      flash.now[:success] = 'Signed in with LinkedIn.'
    end
    @user = current_user
    @user.save
    redirect_to current_user
  end

end
```

Just in case, here is my omniauth.rb file that states the scopes I am requesting for my application:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET'], 
  :scope => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress', :fields => ['id', 'email-address', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'headline', 'industry', 'picture-url', 'public-profile-url', 'location', 'positions', 'educations']
end
```

Can't figure out how to get rid of that second unnecessary and misleading prompt from LinkedIn and would appreciate any guidance!

Thank you.

Comment: Is this configurable on the LinkedIn end? I'm just guessing because that's how Facebook and Twitter do it...

Comment: Not that I know of. Should be able to be configured straight through the omniauth-LinkedIn gem https://github.com/skorks/omniauth-linkedin and the LinkedIn gem:  https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin

Comment: any ideas would be appreciated! still stuck here